# How to avoid the hyperlink on a particular \ref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I use `hyperref` and I produce the pdf via `pdflatex`.
Everytime I use `\ref` I get in the pdf a clickable link and I am happy with it... but I would like to disable the hyperlink in the pdf for one particular `\ref`, is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Package `hyperref` provides `\ref*` and `\pageref*`, the star forms, for this purpose.